# Saving mp3 chunks as a file server-side

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I've been working lately on a project which takes a webm file and converts it to mp3 server side. So far I was getting the file, convert it in my server and then send a link to the user from which they could download the file. The user had to wait until the conversion was done.

Recently I came with the idea of streaming the file to the client-side and save it at the same time.

What I want to achieve is this: **Stream the file to the client-side (chunk by chunk) and once the file stream has finished which means the conversion on the server has finished as well I can save the file.**

**I've tried this**:

```
const { PassThrough } = require("stream");
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
const { writeFile } = require("fs");

let buffers = [];
const passThrough = new PassThrough();
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "`audio/mpeg");

ffmpeg(stream)
            .noVideo()
            .format("mp3")
            .audioBitrate(256)
            .on("error", (error) => console.log(error))
            .on("end", () => {
              res.end();
              buffers = buffers.join("");
              writeFile(`./files/test.mp3`, buffers, (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
              });
            })
            .writeToStream(passThrough);

          passThrough.on("data", (chunk) => {
            buffers.push(chunk);
            res.write(chunk);
          });
```

**What the issue is? Let's say I convert a 2.50min webm video.**

The file is streamed to the client side successfully and it is being saved as it should. It is also playable and the size of the file is around 5MB.

**The file saved on the server though is around 9MB, it is saved as an mp3 file but when I try to listen to it, it gives me this error**:

**Audacity**: "Audacity did not recognize the type of the file. Try installing FFmpeg."

**Browser**: "No video with supported format and MIME type found."

**Windows Media Player**: "We cannot open test.mp3. This may be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect or the file is corrupt."